# getConnections method of node.js tcp server not defined

Tags: node.js

```
var server = net.createServer(function(c) {
    ...
})
server.getConnections(function(err, count){
    console.log("count", count);
})
```

I get the following error.

```
Object #<Server> has no method 'getConnections'
```

1. How to use `getConnections` of a tcp server?

I'm using node version *v0.10.16*

Comment: If you are just after the count, you can use `server.connections`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why your code doesn't work. While having the request to `getConnections` outside of the connection callback is not necessary typical, it worked in my tests. *`server.connections` is deprecated per the documentation, so it's use is discouraged.*

Using `telnet localhost 1337`, a really poor echo socket is emulated below, and the current count of connections is displayed. The code below worked in my tests:

```
var server = require('net').createServer();

server.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
       socket.write(data);
    });
    server.getConnections(function(err, count) {
       console.log("Connections: " + count);
    });
});
server.listen(1337);
```

Comment: OMG. if I run the code in command line like, node test.js every thing is perfect. If i run the same code in nodeclipse im getting this error. How to slove this ?

Comment: That's really changing the nature of your question. :(. I have no familiarity with nodeclipse. I use WebStorm for all of my Node development.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var net = require('net');
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var server = net.createServer(function(c) {
    ...`enter code here`
eventEmitter.emit('event1');

})


eventEmitter.on('event1', function(){
   server.getConnections(function(err, count){
        console.log("count", count);
    })
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Catalin.  Could you expand this answer with a bit of explanation as to what you're doing and why?  Just code on its own isn't very helpful as an answer.  Thanks.